# How to run 2 methods concurrently in same class with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I would like to use 2 methods in the same class concurrently using the same object in Java. For example:

```
public class aThread extends Thread {

    int countA = 0;
    int countB = 0;

    int countA(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            countA++;
        }
        return countA;
    }
    int countB(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            countB++;
        }
        return countB;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run(); 
        //should there be something here?
    }
}
```

And using this methods in another method:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        aThread myThread = new aThread();

        myThread.countA(); //I want these 2 methods to run concurrently.
        myThread.countB();
        //how do I use myThread.start() here?

    }
}
```

note: They don't have to be synchronized.

Comment: And what prevents you from doing that?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Because the two methods wouldn't run concurrently then.

Comment: because they are being used in different parts of the system from the same object. Also, there is more than 2 methods and I can't make just a method to call them all at once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your task. You have quiet easy situation when threads should not be synchronized.

You can use [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) from Java Concurrency:

```
public class ConcurrentCode {
    
    private int countA = 0;
    private int countB = 0;
    
    int countA(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            countA++;
        }
        System.out.println(countA);
        return countA;
    }
    
    int countB(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            countB++;
        }
        System.out.println(countB);
        return countB;
    }
    
    public void execute(){
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    
        // method reference introduced in Java 8
        executorService.submit(this::countA);
        executorService.submit(this::countB);
    
        // close executorService
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ConcurrentCode().execute();
    }
    
}
```

Remember to shutdown `ExecutorService` otherwise your application won't stop because it will have alive threads.

Or you can have the simplest approach using vanilla [Java threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

```
public void executeInNativeThreads(){
    
    // starts new thread and executes countA in it
    new Thread(this::countA).start();

    // starts new thread and executes countB in it
    new Thread(this::countB).start();
    
}
```

To get computation results you can get the [`Future<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) from `executorService` and then you have a choice:

- poll `Future` if it is done
- wait until the `Future` will be completed.
- wait explicitly for a certain timeout

Here is an example:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Future<Integer> future1 = executorService.submit(this::countA);
    Future<Integer> future2 = executorService.submit(this::countB);

    // wait until result will be ready
    Integer result1 = future1.get();

    // wait only certain timeout otherwise throw an exception
    Integer result2 = future2.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("result1 = " + result1);
    System.out.println("result2 = " + result2);

    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Note, while we are explicitly waiting for result of `future1`, `future2` is still being executed in another thread. It means that there won't be big delay in computation of `future2` in particularly this example.

Also, take a look at [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) which is used in asynchronous computations.

Comment: Worth of note: Class `aThread` doesn't need to `extends Thread` when doing this.

Comment: How can I retrive the return of the value this way?

Comment: @EmreDanisan there are several ways to achieve this. You can get a `Future<Integer>` from `submit` methods and then poll them or wait until response will be ready. I will update my answer

Comment: @EmreDanisan happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

To run your code concurrently, you need at least two threads :

```
public class MyClass {

    int countA = 0;
    int countB = 0;

    public int countA(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            countA++;
        }
        return countA;
    }

    public int countB(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            countB++;
        }
        return countB;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass() ;
        ExecutorService  executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2) ;
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Integer>>() ;
        tasks.add(myClass::countA) ;
        tasks.add(myClass::countB) ;
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks) ;
        System.out.println(results.get(0).get()+" "+results.get(1).get());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

You can track the result with: results.

Comment: You are forgetting the result of the methods

Comment: You can track the result with : results .

Answer (score 0):

Solutions using `Stream` API.

**Async:**

```java
    public void runInParallel(Runnable... tasks) {
        Stream.of(tasks).map(Thread::new).forEach(Thread::start);
    }
```

**Sync:**

```java
    public void runInParallel(Runnable... tasks) {
        Stream.of(tasks).parallel().forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
```

How to use:

```java
    public void execute() {
        runInParallel(
                this::countA,
                this::countB);
    }

    public void executeWithParams() {
        runInParallel(
                () -> countA(5),
                () -> countA(10));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to create Runnables to invoke the methods you are trying to run concurrently within independent threads

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final aThread myThread = new aThread();

  Runnable a = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      myThread.countA();
    }
  });
  Runnable b = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      myThread.countB();
    }
  });
    new Thread(a).start();
    new Thread(b).start();
}
```

Comment: Or you could use lambda, or rather method reference: `new Thread(myThread::countA).start();`

Comment: Worth of note: Class `aThread` doesn't need to `extends Thread` when doing this.

Comment: You are forgetting the result of the methods